# Can't access more than the first child node of its parent when parsing XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xml-parsing

How my XML node structure works, is I have multiple children elements of parents that also occur multiple times.  I am able to get to the children elements, but only the first one of each parent.  I am also trying to insert the data in the children elements into MySQL.  I just can't seem to access any child element after the first one.  When I echo `count()`, I'm able to get a total count of the children elements for each reoccurring parent, but I can't seem to work with that data. Parsing XML is fairly new to me, and my PHP is a bit rusty, so please forgive me.  What am I not getting?

Note: The data I'm concerned with is in the mt nodes. The immediate parent of the mt nodes is the mi node.

```
$string = file_get_contents('file1.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

foreach ($xml->md as $mt_tag) {
    if (isset($mt_tag->mi->mt)) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO xmlData(
                xml_data
                ) VALUES (
                '{$mt_tag->mi->mt}'
                )";
        mysql_query($query, $connection);
        echo count($mt_tag->mi->mt);
        echo "<br />";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Creation Failed.<p>";
        echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . "</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure xmlData() is supported in MySQL? I think that might be SQL Server only (I could be wrong, but didn't see anything about it in a quick search)...

Comment: I also recommend placing some sample XML as you are trying to work with here

Comment: @ Brett  I think it should be fine because the data I'm concerned with is just a string of letter characters. I'm also able to insert the strings from the first child of the parent, just not any after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre missing a for loop on the mt nodes:

```
foreach ($xml->md as $md_tag) {
       if (isset($md_tag->mi->mt)) {

              foreach ($md_tag->mi->mt as $mt) {
                    //do something
              }
       }
}
```

Please make sure to change this which is inconsistent

```
foreach ($xml->md as $mt_tag) {
```

to

```
foreach ($xml->md as $md_tag) {
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! I kept getting tripped up on the child nodes.  I've been trying to figure this out for awhile, and it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You must consider reading this:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php